# System call open() seems to be setting file permissions randomly when creating a file

Tags: c, linux, filesystems, system, system-calls

I'm using the open system call to both create and open a file in the following manner:

```
fileID = open("aFile", O_CREAT|O_RDWR|O_TRUNC);
```

I expect the file to be created with read and write permissions, and sometimes it is, but only times when I run `ls -l` I see just w, or just r, or just x, or ws, or rwx, etc. If I run my program with the system call 3 times, I may get 3 different file permissions set for `aFile` each time. I don't know what could be causing the problem since it seems to be being set randomly. Any ideas as to what may be the cause?

Comment: are you using a network drive? or local drive?

Comment: You have to specify the access mode. `int open(const char *pathname, int flags, mode_t mode);` "The mode argument specifies the file mode bits be applied when a
 new  file  is  created.   This  argument  must  be supplied when O_CREAT or O_TMPFILE is specified in flags; if  neither  O_CREAT nor O_TMPFILE is specified, then mode is ignored." If you don't specify the mode, it may be a random value (undefined behavior).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`open()` takes a third argument which takes effect when creating a file. This argument is a set of flags that modify the access mode of the new file. If you don't set a value for this argument, the `open()` function will be provided with whatever happens to be in the register or stack position that applies to this argument -- depending on the specific system and compiler. In any case, it's unlikely to be what you intend, and will depend in an unpredictable way on the preceding code.

On Unix-like systems, `man 2 open` should give you all the details.